# Does calling redux select after put in a saga wait for store to update?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, saga

I have a scenario where we are adding an item to a list using by dispatching an action that calls a reducer to update the state, and then trying to grab that updated list immediately after. Here's a simple example:

```
yield put(addItem(newItem));
const items = yield select(getItems);
// do something with items
```

My question is, is the new item guaranteed to be in `items`, or is this a race condition? I understand that `yield` is waiting for the action to be dispatched, but I'm concerned that the action will be dispatched which will trigger the saga to continue, then the selector is called, and then the reducer actually updates the state. Is this a valid concern? Or will the `put` not even return until the reducer has run first?

I understand I can simply call `select` first, dispatch the action, and then locally within the saga update `items` like this:

```
const items = yield select(getItems);
yield put(addItem(newItem));
const updatedItems = [
    ...items,
    newItem
];
// do something with items
```

However, I would like to avoid this because it would essentially be recreating the reducer logic within the saga, and require any changes within the reducer to also be reflected in the saga. It would be cleaner to `select` the updated object from the state after `put`.

Comment: Put should update the state before yielding back to the saga, according to the docs.
https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#putaction